# Common practice when using gnu patch manually

Tags: diff

Say I have a locally modified file `my_V1` and the newer official version of the same file: `V2` , but their common ancestor `V1` is gone.

And I want to merge **some of** changes of `my_V1` into `V2` in order to get a `my_V2`, what is the common practice to diff them, review the patch, and applying the patch.

What I am doing is mostly like

```
diff -U V2 my_V1 > my_patch      #generate a unified patch
vi my_patch                      #review it
patch V2 -o my_V2 -i my_patch    #apply
```

And when I reviewing and picking lines to merge into V2, it seems I must manually specify the new position and length of every chunk, or patch simply refuse to apply it.

Is this what we have to bear when using gnu diff?

or, am I supposed to use patch and diff in another more more elegant way?

Comment: do you have the possibility to use a GUI diff tool? it would be much much more practical than this method.

Comment: @armel  Thanks for telling me that. I am using beyondcompare in workplace, but didn't buy a personal license yet. If using only `diff` is hard, I would consider buy another license to use it in home.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [patchutils](http://freecode.com/projects/patchutils), especially the *filterdiff* command. It can be used to review a diff and keep only some changes.